# Read More in php

Tags: php, mysql

i try to make read more option for my work and i create this code :

```
<?php
      $string=$polnews['articale']; 
    if (strlen($string) > 500) {

        // truncate string
        $stringCut = substr($string, 0, 500);

        // make sure it ends in a word so assassinate doesn't become ass...
        $string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a href="view_articles.php?aid=$polnews[aid]">Read More</a>'; 
    }
    echo $string;?>
```

but the link not working.

Comment: If it is just text, I would echo the whole article and hide / show part of it with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you cannot interpolate variables inside single quoted strings.

```
$string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' '))."... <a href=\"view_articles.php?aid=$polnews['aid']\">Read More</a>";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'<a href="view_articles.php?aid=$polnews[aid]">Read More</a>'
^                                                           ^
```

It is within single quotes, so your `$polnews[aid]` does not get interpolated, and is read in literally. Variable names will be expanded within **[double quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)**.

You **could** put it in a double-quoted string, **or** do

```
.'<a href="view_articles.php?aid=' . $polnews[aid] . '>Read More</a>'
```

Comment: @Prash had a math class this evening :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a href="view_articles.php?aid='.$polnews[aid].'">Read More</a>';
```

The other answers are fine, this works, too.